# How to displays name of days of week

Tags: reactjs, jsx, date-fns

I'm starting react and I follow a tutorial for make a calendar with date-fns, but the version of date-fns in the tutorial is different to my version.

I meet a problem to display the name of the days week.

Code of tutorial (old version of date-fns) :

```js
import dateFns from "date-fns";

renderDays() {
  const dateFormat = "dddd";
  const days = [];
  let startDate = dateFns.startOfWeek(this.state.currentMonth);
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    days.push(
      <div className="col col-center" key={i}>
        {dateFns.format(dateFns.addDays(startDate, i), dateFormat)}
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <div className="days row">{days}</div>;
}
```

My code with new version of date-fns :

```js
import { format, startOfWeek, addDays} from 'date-fns';

renderDays() {
    const dateFormat = "dddd";
    const days = [];

    let startDate = startOfWeek(this.state.currentMonth);

    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      days.push(
        <div className="col col-center" key={i}>
          {format(addDays(startDate, i), dateFormat)}
        </div>
      );
    }

    return <div className="days row">{days}</div>;
  }
```

I don't understand what to do to make the names appear... Currently it shows me numbers.

Sorry, I can't put images to show you the results of each code, but here is the link of tutorial : https://medium.com/@moodydev/create-a-custom-calendar-in-react-3df1bfd0b728

Do you have ideas for help me, please ?

Thanks

Comment: Try with dateFormat ="eeee"

Comment: The only difference I see here is the destructured import and the missing return.

Comment: @Medi that's the problem, I don't see what more I can do... The only difference is that you have to import one by one the elements.
For return is an oversight on my part when publishing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display only the day of the week set `dateFormat` to `EEEE`. For other format options refer to [date-fns docs](https://date-fns.org/v2.21.1/docs/format)

Comment: It's good thank you, I hadn't looked in the right place...

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer if it`s ok